# ASP.NET generating an or query from a list of ids

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a list of ids coming in to my endpoint:

```
var idsArr = token.ToObject<int[]>();
```

and I have a query called qry

How can I generate a where condition from the list of ids so that I can call

```
qry.Where(whereClause);
```

Basically, I would like the following list:

```
new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
```

to turn into this:

```
SELECT from table where
id = 1 or
id = 2 or 
id = 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `Linq` or `Ado.net` ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Using Linq please.

Comment: did you try Any() or Contains()? `qry.Where(a => idsArr.Contains(a.id));` `qry.Where(a => idsArr.Any(b => b == a.id));`  something like that

Comment: @JamieD77 pretty sure that wont work because idsArr is local not in the database.

Comment: LINQ generates the query (locally) and sends it to the database..

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Comment: What Jamie suggested should work. Instead of assuming with `pretty sure that wont work`, you *should* try, and then an answer can be formulated. :)

Comment: @JamieD77 Yes, I know but I am pretty sure Linq .any or .contains does not work when comparing local lists to db sets. Nevertheless, I am not sure. I will try it and report back.

Comment: @JamieD77 my apologies. I just tried it and it does work. I learned something today. Thank you. If you post an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq

```
context.table.Where(q=>q.id == list[0] || q.id == list[1]|| q.id == list[2]).ToList()
```

This may help you.